# What is the use of "title" and "description" in widget configuration intent?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

After we have uploaded our app to App store, we receive the following warning email from App Store.

```
ITMS-90626: Invalid Siri Support - Localized title for custom intent: 'Configuration' not found for locale: fr

ITMS-90626: Invalid Siri Support - Localized description for custom intent: 'Configuration' not found for locale: zh-hk

ITMS-90626: Invalid Siri Support - Localized title for custom intent: 'Configuration' not found for locale: zh-hant

ITMS-90626: Invalid Siri Support - Localized description for custom intent: 'Configuration' not found for locale: en

ITMS-90626: Invalid Siri Support - Localized description for custom intent: 'Configuration' not found for locale: pt-br

ITMS-90626: Invalid Siri Support - Localized description for custom intent: 'Configuration' not found for locale: zh-hans
```

Currently, we do not localized every strings. We only localize those fields which we feel are reasonable.

### Xcode

[image]

### Configuration intent executed in English locale

[image]

### Configuration intent executed in Chinese locale

[image]

We do not localize fields **title** and **description** (Circled in green), because we aren't sure where they are being used. We do not see how they are being used in UI.

Does anyone how **title** and **description** are being used, so that we know what the correct value should be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are kind of hidden but they show in "Shortcuts"

`Tap on Shortcuts > + > Type the app name in search bar > Click on "info" button.`

You will see the title when you search and the title and description when you click on the "info" button.

[image]

[image]